# Symfony throwing ServiceCircularReferenceException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I am using Symfony 2.7 and i am writing all logs to data based on below tutorial

https://nehalist.io/logging-events-to-database-in-symfony/

In service i have

```
 monolog.db_handler:
        class: AppBundle\Util\MonologDBHandler
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

in monlog db handler i have following

```
class MonologDBHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * MonologDBHandler constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Called when writing to our database
     * @param array $record
     */
    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        $logEntry = new Log();
        $logEntry->setMessage($record['message']);
        $logEntry->setLevel($record['level']);
        $logEntry->setLevelName($record['level_name']);
        $logEntry->setExtra($record['extra']);
        $logEntry->setContext($record['context']);

        $this->em->persist($logEntry);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

if i enable dev mode i am getting following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException:
>   Circular reference detected for service
>   "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path:
>   "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager ->
>   doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> monolog.logger.doctrine ->
>   monolog.monolog.db_handler".

I know this error due to service doctrine injection .how i can sole this issue.Thank you

Comment: The article was written for S3+.  There used to be a lot of problems like this since the event manager was dependent on all of it's listeners.  So making a listener dependent on the entity manager would result in a circular dependency.  This was cleaned up a bit in 3.x.  Maybe even 2.8.  Not sure.  All I can really suggest is checking the 2.7 docs for an example.

Comment: @Cerad.thanks is there any sollution to fix this .i cant upgrade symfony since it has to change lots of things

Comment: @Cerad.if i disable prod false then woring fine.it throw error only when i change to true

Comment: I would have to setup a 2.7 environment and mess around a bit.  The only way I know for sure that would work would be to access the entity manager via the global $kernel variable.  Not the ideal solution but might be your best bet.

Comment: @Cerad.thanks for your effort. i am new to symfony.if you get sollution kndly post .thank you

Comment: @Cerad.only i get error if i enable dev mode in app.php $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

Comment: I assume you only have problems in dev mode, because Doctrine's EntityManager is logging debug messages which means the EntityManager will require the listener and the other way around which the container is not able to resolve. A possible way around this would be to have a separate logger other than the Db-Logger being used for logging in the entity manager.

Comment: @dbrumann.i have changed now to all logs instead of single db channel in config.if you have sollution.kindly post it thank you

Answer (score -2):

This approach is a really bad idea and should be avoided but you can get rid of the circular reference by accessing the entity manager via the global $kernel variable.

```
class MonologDBHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        global $kernel;
        $em = $kernel->getContainer()-get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

And then remove the arguments section from your service definition.

Comment: getting Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Comment: I did say it was a bad idea:) The whole article seems a bit suspicious.  The write method is probably being triggered when the entity manager is flushed so when you write your log object out it flushes again and loops around.  Make a [second entity manager](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) just for logging (possible using a second database) and it will probably work.  In fact using a second entity manager will probably allow your original code to work.